# Can't find kobject for use in sysfs_notify()

Tags: linux-kernel, sysfs

I am working on a driver that creates a sysfs attribute file.  It is intended that an application be notified of changes to this attribute by using the `poll()` method.  I intend to use the `sysfs_notify()` function for this.  This is easy to do as long as you have the `kobject` for the attribute (`sysfs_notify()` requires that as the first parameter).  Getting the `kobject` is easy enough if using `sysfs_create_file()` and related functions.

I read this post on [correctly creating a sysfs file](http://kroah.com/log/blog/2013/06/26/how-to-create-a-sysfs-file-correctly/) that solves a possible race condition between userspace notification that the device is present, and the creation of the sysfs files.  This solution is also much cleaner.

However, I cannot figure out how to get the `kobject` for each of the attributes (or parent) that I can use in `sysfs_notify()`.  At one point structures such as `struct device_driver` had a member of `struct kobject kobj;`.  That was replaced (10ish years ago) with `struct driver_private *p;`.  This private structure now contains the actual `kobject` and is not available for use.

Is there a new form of `sysfs_notify()` that I can use, or is there another way of getting the correct `kobject`?  I may have to go back to "manually" creating the sysfs attribute otherwise.

Comment: It's probably an old question, but I can answer this about `platform_driver` and `miscdevice`.